# Is there an immutable version of Object.assign?

Tags: javascript, immutability, assign

I want to mix two objects in JavaScript:

```
let a = {x: 1, y: 2, z:3};
let b = {x:10, y: 20};

let c = Object.assign(a, b);
```

This gives the correct value for `c`:

```
Object { x: 10, y: 20, z: 3 }
```

But now `a` has been modified too!

```
Object { x: 10, y: 20, z: 3 }
```

Is there a way to assign `a` onto `b` into a new object?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The first argument to [assign](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) is the *target*. So it's going to get changed. You can simply pass an empty object for your target if you don't want any of the sources to change:

```js
let a = {x: 1, y: 2, z:3};
let b = {x:10, y: 20};

let c = Object.assign({},a, b);
console.log(c);
console.log(a);    // a is unchanged
```

Comment: It will not be immutable if the values are references.

Answer (score 13):

You could use the [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator):

```js
let a = {x: 1, y: 2, z: 3};
let b = {x: 10, y: 20};

let c = {
  ...a,
  ...b
}

console.log(c);
console.log(a);
```

Comment: The spread operator is a beautiful thing. Babel plugin: https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-object-rest-spread/

Answer (score 4):

Definitively the **spread operator**. It helps to add a single property, like styling CSS in JS. But be aware that it's currently [only in stage 4](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-object-rest-spread#status-of-this-proposal) of EcmaScript.

```
const lessStyle = {
    color: 'blue',
    backgroundColor: 'yellow'
};

const moreStyle = {...lessStyle, color: 'red'};
// lessStyle is not affected
```

You can use it today in Typescript and JSX though.

Answer (score 0):

```
let a = {x: 1, y: 2, z:3};
let b = {x:10, y: 20};

let c = Object.assign({}, a, b);
```

You need the {} within the assign method for the first object because if you read the documentation for Object.assign method here https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign#Parameters It states that the first parameter is the target object and the rest are the sources. so right now you are assigning b to a and returning the new a to c. So if your first argument is an empty object this won't happen.